# Wordpress 'If' Statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, function

I have made a custom author.php page in my wordpress theme that successfully pulls in all the member's details from the DB.

I want to add an if statement before the details are brought it that only shows the info if a `_mgm_user_status = expired`. `_mgm_user_status` is in the db as `wp_usermeta`. These details are all in the db, I just can't work out how to add the if statement before hand.

If the users status is not 'expired' all the info should pull in as usual. If it is 'expired' then a warning should be presented like '`<p>Sorry, user not found</p>`'.

Thanks for your help with this guys.

Like so??

```
<?php
                                                $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                                                if ($user_id == 0) {
                                                    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
                                                } else {
                                                    echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
                                                }
                                                ?><?php
                                                    $userID = intval($author);
                                            if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
                                            $curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
                                            else :
                                            $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
                                            endif;
                                            ?><?php $is_expired = get_user_meta($user_id,     '_mgm_user_status', true);
                                                if(!empty($is_expired) && $is_expired ==     'expired') {
                                                    echo 'Sorry, user not found';
                                                }
?>

<ul class="profile-list">
    <li>
    <?php echo get_avatar($curauth->ID, 95, get_bloginfo('template_url').''); ?></li>

    <li><strong>Member No.:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_membership_id; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_title; ?></li>

    <li><strong>First Name:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->first_name; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Surname:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->last_name; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Job Title:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_job_title; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_email; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Organisation:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_organisation; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Type of Organisation:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_types_of_organisation; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Service Provided:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_service; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Address:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_address; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Town/City:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_city; ?></li>

    <li><strong>County:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_state; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Postcode:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_zip; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Region:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_region; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Country:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_country; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Telephone:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_phone; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Mobile:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_mobile; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Fax:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_fax; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Website:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_website_url; ?></li>

    <li><strong>Other Info:</strong>
    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_other_info; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please put only relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I edited this code. This wil works fine for you.

```
  <?php
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id == 0) {
            echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
        } else {
            $curauth = get_userdata(intval($user_id));

            $is_expired = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_mgm_user_status', true);
            if(!empty($is_expired) && $is_expired ==  'expired') {
                echo 'Sorry, user not found';
            }else {
                ?>

                <ul class="profile-list">
                    <li>
                    <?php echo get_avatar($curauth->ID, 95, get_bloginfo('template_url').''); ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Member No.:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_membership_id; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_title; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>First Name:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->first_name; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Surname:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->last_name; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Job Title:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_job_title; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_email; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Organisation:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_organisation; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Type of Organisation:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_types_of_organisation; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Service Provided:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_service; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Address:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_address; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Town/City:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_city; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>County:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_state; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Postcode:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_zip; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Region:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_region; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Country:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_country; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Telephone:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_phone; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Mobile:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_mobile; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Fax:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_fax; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Website:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_website_url; ?></li>

                    <li><strong>Other Info:</strong>
                    <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_other_info; ?></li>
                </ul>
                <?php 
                } 
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Would the above amend to my author.php work? I'm not great at combining php, sorry.

Comment: Pardon me.Can you tell me what is the $author values ?

Comment: This is in the functions.php, i think it pulls in the userdata as deleting it prevents the page from working:                               function new_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_slug = 'members-directory';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
    }

Comment: Thanks for your help with this - you're being greatly helpfuland i really appreciate it.

Comment: I edited my answer after edit your code. Please try this edited answer.

Comment: That didnt solve it. Sorry. I can pay you to work on this if you like. £10.00 and i'll provide the full author.php and functions.php file?

Comment: can you tell me what's the error now ? Please replace the below lines $is_expired = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, '_mgm_user_status', true);
  if(!empty($is_expired) && $is_expired ==  'expired') {
   
with this
  if(!empty($curauth->_mgm_user_status) && $curauth->_mgm_user_status ==  'expired') {

Comment: It doesnt pull in the member's info, it pulls in a few fields from the admin's user details. Its a members directory we've made so it shouldnt be the current user. I think $author was important too as removing it kills the fields.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user  
If these will not help you then,I will check your files but not now after 2 hours. you will send me your details on my email

Comment: my email is agrawalkapil987@gmail.com